# Finding subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> I need to find all nontrivial subgroups of $G:=\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ (with multiplication without zero)

**My attempt:**

$G$ is cyclic so the order of subgroup of $G$ must be $2,3,4,6$

Now to look for $g\in G$ such that $g^2=e,g^3=e,g^4=e,g^6=e$

$$\begin{align}
&12^1=12\mod 13\\
&12^2=1\mod 13\\
\end{align}$$
$\Rightarrow \color{blue}{\{12,1\}}$ is a subgroup of order $2$

$$\begin{align}
&3^1=3\mod 13\\
&3^2=9\mod 13\\
&3^3=1\mod 13\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
&9^1=9\mod 13\\
&9^2=3\mod 13\\
&9^3=1\mod 13\\
\end{align}$$

$\Rightarrow \color{blue}{\{9,3,1\}}$ is a subgroup of order $3$

$$\begin{align}
&5^1=5\mod 13\\
&5^2=12\mod 13\\
&5^3=8\mod 13\\
&5^4=1\mod 13\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
&8^1=8\mod 13\\
&8^2=12\mod 13\\
&8^3=5\mod 13\\
&8^4=1\mod 13\\
\end{align}$$

$\Rightarrow \color{blue}{\{1,5,12,8\}}$ is a subgroup of order $4$

$$\begin{align}
&4^1=4\mod 13\\
&4^2=3\mod 13\\
&4^3=12\mod 13\\
&4^4=9\mod 13\\
&4^5=10\mod 13\\
&4^6=1\mod 13\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
&10^1=10\mod 13\\
&10^2=9\mod 13\\
&10^3=12\mod 13\\
&10^4=3\mod 13\\
&10^5=4\mod 13\\
&10^6=1\mod 13\\
\end{align}$$

$\Rightarrow \color{blue}{\{4,3,12,9,10,1\}}$ is a subgroup of order $6$

> Is it correct? is there any easier method?

Comment: yeah...!!! It is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $2$ is a generator of $\Bbb{Z}_{13}^*$ you have that the subgroups are exactly
$$\{ \langle 2^n \rangle : n \mbox{ divides } 12\}$$
i.e.
$$\langle 2 \rangle \\ \langle 2^2 \rangle = \langle 4 \rangle \\ \langle 2^3 \rangle = \langle 8 \rangle \\ \langle 2^4 \rangle = \langle 3 \rangle \\ \langle 2^6 \rangle = \langle -1 \rangle \\ \langle 2^{12} \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle \\$$

Comment: $2^6=12 \mod 13$

Comment: so $1$ is generator? but the order of $\langle 1 \rangle$ is $\infty$

Comment: order of $\langle 1 \rangle=\infty$?? $1$ is identity element $1$ generates trivial subgroup

Comment: sorry, the order is one

Comment: @Crostul Thanks

Comment: @Nehorai: $2^6\equiv 12\equiv -1\mod13$.

Comment: @Crostul: $\;\langle 2^2\rangle=;\langle 2^3\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is right. As, I  am noting that(may be i'm wrong), you are applying that "A cyclic subgroup of order $4$ must contain $2$ elements of order $4$ and  $1$ element of order $2$, and you searching those elements and listing them. You can reduce your calculation by searching one element of each order, and then you can generate your required subgroups, e.g. $5$ is element of order $4$ so,

$$<5>=\{1,5,8,12\}$$ is subgroup of order $4$